# Local stateless EJBs vs Remote

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, layer

I'm kind of a newbie in EJBs,but I've been given an EJB tier to improve.
This tier consists of an EJB wich exposes the operations available:

```
@Stateless(name = "myejb")
public class Facade implements FacadeRemote
{
    @EJB
    private EntityAHomeLocal entityAHome;

    @EJB
    private EntityBHomeLocal entityBHome;

// methods signatures and implementations
}
```

As you can see this EJB use other local EJBs that manage operations on entities.

```
@Stateless
public class EntityAHome implements EntityAHomeLocal
{
    @PersistenceContext(name="myUnit")
    private EntityManager manager;


    // methods signatures and implementations
}
```

I'm having hard time to fully understand the architecture of this tier.

- Is this kind of architrcture common ?
- Are local stateless EJB managed throught a pool of instances just like remote    stateless EJBs ?
- Would it still work even if entityAHome and entityBHome were remote EJBs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the spec only says stateless beans are "typically" pooled (section 4.3.10.2), so the behaviour for local beans is vendor-specific, but in practice I believe all the major vendors do ([for example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ejb/session.html)).

Local and remote interfaces are almost entirely interchangeable, but with extra deployment restrictions (i.e. they must be deployed locally, of course), and some calls to local interfaces use pass-by-reference semantics, whereas remote interfaces always use pass-by-value ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abecg/index.html)).

I can't see anything that would stop that code working with remote interfaces, although I think some of the naming is confusing - a session bean (`@Stateless`) is different from an entity, and in EJB terminology "home" refers to a kind of factory class, which I don't think is your intention here (?).  Also, be aware that switching to `@Remote` can add a performance overhead, as the second link notes.

Comment: what about transaction propagation ? I mean if one of my local ejb use another local ejb and nn want to propagate the transaction..,would this require that the ejb must be managed by the same container ?

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at section 13.7 of the EJB spec (http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/) - this discusses distributed transactions with remote clients.

Comment: specifications for me are somewhat hard to read, could you suggest me a textbook to study on the subject ?

Comment: Personally I got a long way with Head First EJB as a starter, then the spec to follow up.  (It really is very readable, I do recommend it!)  But from the questions you're asking, I think you'd find the introductory level books a bit basic for your needs.

Comment: does head first ejb covers EJB 3.0 spec or earlier ones ?

Comment: Ah yes, it's only EJB 2.0 (I'm amazing they don't have a more recent edition!).  As I say, this worked for me - not claiming it's the best way.